# Chrome and Firefox Sourcemaps Not Working

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, babeljs, source-maps

Sourcemaps seem to have stopped working for me in both Chrome and Firefox. The browsers show the source file names. When I click on the file I get this message, Cannot GET /.tmp/includes/jsbin/marketing.js. marketing.js is the name of the source file. I get the same message for each source file.

I'm using Grunt as my task runner. Here is the workflow.

1. Babel transpiles my javascript to a .tmp folder.
2. Uglify concats and minifies the javascript files in the .tmp folder and outputs them to a dist folder.
3. Uglify creates a sourcemap file.

When I look at the sourcemap file it has the correct paths to the source files in the .tmp folder.

```
{"version":3,"sources":["../../../.tmp/includes/jsbin/check_compat.js","../../../.tmp/includes/jsbin/marketing.js"],
```

This is a new workflow for me. In other projects when I didn't use babel things worked just fine. I'm having this issue in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox, even the canary versions of those browsers.

The babel task does not concat.

**Update 2015/10/27**

For some reason the .tmp folder isn't getting served. So the browser sees that a source file exists from the sourcemap but the source file is empty because the server doesn't serve it.

Here is my grunt task:

```
config: {
    app: 'app',
    dev: 'dev',
    dist: 'dist',
    tmp: '.tmp'
},
dist: {
    options: {
        base: ['<%= config.tmp %>', '<%= config.dist %>'],
        open: {
            target: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>?envMode=apiary&testing=true'
        }
    }
}
```

You can see the files in the dev tools.

[image]

If I right the file click and select "Open link in new tab" I get the error message `Cannot GET /.tmp/includes/jsbin/check_compat.js`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct reference at the bottom of your js file?

Should be something like:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```